# Creating new Component on Yii give me an error

Tags: class, yii, websocket, components

I'm trying to create a new Component on Yii. The file name is ChatManager.php and so is the class one (without '.php', of course), and extends CApplicationComponent. But I've a problem. When I run it from terminal, it gives me this error:

```
Class 'CApplicationComponent' not found in /../
```

so I've added in config/main.php the following:

```
'preload'=>array('log','ChatManager'),
```

But still not working. I think the problem is that this class also manages WebSockets, and when i run it, my application isn't instantiated. Is true? Or there's another kind of problem?

Answer (score 0):

When running Yii from Terminal or the command line, it uses a different set of config files (by default). So it won't be using `main.php` (unless you've told it to). You should have different config files for the web and console environments though.

The config file being used will be defined in `/protected/yiic.php`, or your custom console index file.

The default config file is `console.php`, so have a look in `protected/config/console.php` and make sure the settings you need are in there - particularly the importing of any other classes via the `import => array(...)` section.

You may also need to define your component in the `components => array(...)` section of the config file, something like this:

```
'components' => array(

    // All the existing components...

    'ChatManager' => array(
         'class' => 'application.components.ChatManager',
    ),

),
```